# How to make a centered, non-bold abstract and section titles

Tags: sectioning, abstract, section-titles

I'm writing a paper on Overleaf, but I have a couple of issues. Firstly, when I use `begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}` the word 'Abstract' comes up in bold and centered above the text, with only the A in capitals, as shown below.
[image]

How can I

1. Make the word Abstract all in capitals
2. Make the word Abstract not in bold
3. Make the word Abstract *next* to the text, eg like in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.07890.pdf) paper

Please note; I don't necessarily want to change all these things all at once, I'd like to be able to change them one at a time preferably.

Secondly, I'd like to make similar chapters and sections titles eg to the ones in the aforementioned paper. I am currently using `\begin{section]...\end{section}` but the section titles come out in bold and are on the left of the page; I'd like each new section title to be like the ones in the aforementioned article; ie centered and not in bold (as well as in capitals hopefully), while still above the text.

Thank you for your help.

This is my preamble:
`\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}`

Comment: You might be interested in the  `abstract` package, which has a `runin` option.

Comment: @Bernard thanks, what is a `runin` option?

Comment: For sections, it means the main text starts on the same line as the section title. I didn't test it with abstract, but I suppose it has the same meaning.

Comment: @Bernard I only want the word 'abstract' to be next to the text, not the section titles.  To make it work for the abstract, what exactly should I add? `\usepackage{abstract,runin}`?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Please post your `MWE` in a full format, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`...

Comment: @MadyYuvi sorry, what it a `MWE`?

Comment: Please refer `https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks`

Comment: You should add \usepackage[runin]{abstract}`. This won't change your section titles.

Comment: MWE is the acronym of Minimal Working Example.

Comment: @Bernard thanks so mcuh for the \usepackage[runin]{abstract} idea, it works really well :) Have you any idea how I can make the section titles how I want them to be?

Comment: The simplest way to go is with the `titlesec`. Try `\titleformat[block]{\section}{\filcenter\mdseries}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{MakeUppercase}`. It also might be nice to replace `\mdseries` with `\scshape` (if your font has no bold small caps – if it has, simply *add* \scshape).

Comment: @Bernard thanks, I've tried that but the following error comes up: argument of \@xdblarg has an extra }

Comment: Could you post a small complete code reproducing your issue?

Comment: @Bernard: ``\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[runin]{abstract}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\normalfont\scshape{Abstract}.}

\begin{document}

\title{A Paper}
\author{Me }
\date{Today}
\maketitle

\titleformat[block]{\section}{\filcenter\scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{MakeUppercase}

\section{First Section}
Etc

\end{document}``

Comment: I've posted  an example code. If the code I posted in my comment didn't work, it's my fault: I placed the optional shape argument as the first, not the second argument (which is contrary to the usual way). Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to obtain what you want for section titles. I used the  `titlecaps` package to have  the first letter of each  (significant) word capitalised, which looks better with small caps, in my opinion, and  the `§` symbol before the section number. Of course, you just have to remove it from the code if you don't like it.

```
 \documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage{erewhon}
 \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
 \usepackage[runin]{abstract}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\normalfont\scshape{Abstract}.}

 \begin{document}

 \title{A Paper} \author{Me } \date{Today} \maketitle
 \titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\scshape}{\S\,\thesection.}{0.5em}{\titlecap}
 \section{First Section}
 \lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that's great! Is there any way to make the font the same as in my screenshot and the other answer?

Comment: I suppose you used the default.Just remove `\usepackage{erewhon}`  (erewhon is a Adobe Utopia clone, with true smallcaps, superior figures, &c.)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Is there any way I can just remove the `§` symbol while keeping the first letter of each signifiacnt word capitalised?

Comment: Yes – it was only a suggestion. Remove the corresponding code, namely `\S\,` in the third argument.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate you putting so much time into helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may helps you:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm} 
\usepackage[runin]{abstract}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\normalfont\scshape{Abstract}.}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is for test
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I;m sorry to be annying, but that still isn't next the text , although it is an improvement, thanks:( I really like the setout of the paper I provided a link for; do you know how I could make an abstract format like that?

Comment: Check the updated answer... I've just followed `Bernard` suggestion...so credit to him...

Comment: Thanks so much, that works brilliantly! Have you any idea how I can change the section titles as I've detailed above?